# Firebase, password reset keep getting error "An internal error has occured. [ Error code: 13 ]" android

Tags: android, firebase

I have recently switched to the new firebase. When I was using the legacy code I was able to reset the users email with no problem. Now with the new firebase I keep getting the error "An internal error has occurred. [ Error code: 13 ]". Even when I hit the password reset button on my app console I get the same error message on the console. I also followed all the instructions from the site on how to reset the users password.

Here is my code:

```
private void resetPassword() {
    String email = mEmailEditText.getText().toString();

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.sent_temp_password,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }
        })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Any help as to why this is occurring would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also recently switched to the new Firebase console. I had many problems with authentication and I couldn't find any solutions. I backed up on a file the database and the rules, then I deleted the Firebase project and created a new one (**from scratch**, recreated the Firebase project, except for the database and the rules that I saved in advance). It worked. I guess there are many problems with converting a Firebase project from the old console to the new Firebase console.

If you don't find any other solution I recommend you do the same, it doesn't take too long.

Answer (score 1):

In the new Firebase version, before any significant change in any user ( change the user's password or email, or delete the user) , the user must have signed in recently. so in order to guarantee a valid response you need to use the reauthenticate method before calling the change method...

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication. The example below shows
// email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers,
// such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
    .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
   user.reauthenticate(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");

            //Here you can can insert your code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify on my situation which is similar. This happens to all users. I don't have much dedicated to this database. Rebuilding, and will get back, but it's weird it was able to authenticate previously. Mind you I am not coming from an old firebase console to a new one. This project is a fresh new console.